# Calling a class from another form

Tags: forms, class, public, privacy

I am trying to call to class from form2 in C# for, example below is code from "Form2".

```
    private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

         Form1 frontmain = new Form1();
         frontmain.buttonchange();
         this.Hide();
     }
```

This will not excute the class in "Form1" called "buttonchange." Below is the code for the "buttonchange" class:

```
    public void buttonchange()
    {
            button1.Text = workshop1;
            button2.Text = workshop2;
            button3.Text = workshop3;
            button4.Text = workshop4;
            button5.Text = workshop5;
    {
```

I assume it has something to do with privacy settings between form1 and form2 however I have never found the solution. I have always worked around it somehow. Does anyone know what the issue is here?

Comment: One of the issues is that in your click handler you are creating a new instance of Form1 - is that really what you mean to do? If you're trying to refer to an existing instance of Form1 then your click handler code will have no impact on that.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up events on form2 and set up form1 to capture the form1 events.

Here is a link to setting up events:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new instance of `Form1` and calling code upon that, which is probably not what you actually intend to do.

If you're trying to refer to an existing instance of Form1, then you'll need to refer to that (rather than create a new instance).

If an instance of `Form1` spawns the form that your click handler is in, you can refer to it like this:

```
Form1 frontmain = this.Owner as Form1;
```

If an instance of `Form1` doesn't spawn your second form with the click handler, then you will need to take an event-based approach (which is a better approach anyway, as it eliminates dependencies).